# Vimeo player appear like audio

Tags: html, video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I searched a lot before this but i couldn't find something usefull.

Is there any way to make embed Vimeo player to appear like an audio player?

Even in the payed version.

By this i mean not something very fancy like soundcloud, just a simple audio player with controls.

Thanks

Comment: You could hide the embedded video player and create your own controls using the Javascript API https://developer.vimeo.com/player.

Comment: Are you able to hide the embedded video player and still have it play? I am finding that hiding the video player--for example, setting the relevant div to "display: none", stops the player from playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. The Vimeo Player and Vimeo products only support video files at this time. You'll need to use another service like SoundCloud or MixCloud for audio files.